# Не работают стили с подгружаемых файлов

Tags: php, css, cakephp

Стили на сайте работают если добавлять с внешнего источника, если со своих файлов нет. Сайт на CakePHP.

К примеру так работают:

```
    <link href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/prestashop_46528/themes/theme777/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

А вот так не работают:

```
    <?php echo $this->Html->css('normalize'); ?>
```

Comment: Что получается результате выполнения второй строки? Ctrl + U ?

Comment: Ссылки показываются и работают, вот сайт a22m.ru

Comment: у вас приведенный код должен генериорвать ссылку вида `/css/normalize.css`, убедитесь что в `app/webroot/css/` есть соответствующий файл. Ну и приведите строку, генерируемую кейком